# Aggregate based on condition and date

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have a daily dataset that looks like this:

```
date       CMA0013 CMA0047 CMA0052 CMA0067
1975-10-01       0   0.012   0.078       0
1975-10-02       0   0.012   0.078       0
1975-10-03       0   0.012   0.078       0
1975-10-04       0   0.012   0.078       0
1975-10-05       0   0.012   0.078       0
1975-10-06       0   0.012   0.078       0
...
```

In R, I want to count (summarize) by month and year how many records in each column meet the condition `< 0.001`. Let's say to get something like:

```
month   year    CMA0013   CMA0047   CMA0052   CMA0067
   10   1975          6         0         0         6
   11   1975        ...
```

I have tried different options using `aggregate` and `ddply` functions, but, since my knowledge on them is not yet very deep, I couldn't get any satisfactory solution. Thanks to all for any help you provide

An example that didn't work with `ddply`

```
df$year <- year(df$date)
df$month <- month(df$date)

df2 <- ddply(df,~year+month,summarise,
count = length(df[,df$CMA0010 < 0.001]))
```

It doesn't do the sum correctly, and it only does it for one column (CMA0010)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show what you have tried already (and what doesn't work for you) so SO users can see some research effort on your side.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the suggestion. I did a bunch of research, (is a  whole day considered enough?), and tried to adapt solutions of other related posts, to my problem, but couldn't find a satisfactory one. I take your suggestion and will show my attempts in future posts. Cheers

Comment: It's really hard to say what is considered "enough", tbh this was always a topic of extensive meta discussions. Nevertheless the idea is to prevent people coming here and asking for complete solutions without making any effort. If you feel that your web search engine research is exhausted, SO is the place to come to. That's why it is expected to show some specific attempts in the question.

Comment: I totally understand. Indeed, posting was my ultimate resource after a great struggle. I edited my post to show one of my unsatisfactory attempts. I appreciate your suggestion anyways

Comment: Yeah, thanks, good job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way...

```
library(lubridate) #to extract the year and month
df$year <- year(df$date)
df$month <- month(df$date)
df2 <- aggregate(df[, grep("CMA", names(df))], #just summarise columns starting "CMA"
                 by = list(year=df$year, month=df$month), 
                 function(x) sum(x<0.001))

df2
  year month CMA0013 CMA0047 CMA0052 CMA0067
1 1975    10       6       0       0       6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the lubridate package with dplyr:

```
   sum_df <- daily %>%
      mutate(month = lubridate::month(date),
               year= lubridate::year(date)) %>%
      group_by(year, month) %>%
      summarise(CMA0013 = sum(CMA0013 < 0.001),
                #The rest of you sums...
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` and `lubridate` solution, but calculates sum for all `CMA` columns automatically.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
d %>%
    gather(key, value, -date) %>%
    mutate(year = year(date), month = month(date)) %>%
    select(-date) %>%
    group_by(year, month, key) %>%
    summarize(N = sum(value < 0.001)) %>%
    spread(key, N)

# A tibble: 1 x 6
# Groups:   year, month [1]
   year month CMA0013 CMA0047 CMA0052 CMA0067
* <dbl> <dbl>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1  1975    10       6       0       0       6
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiarized with most of the syntax (especially  %>%), but will try to learn from it